# Convert CSV to a Formatted Spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have a dynamically generated CSV file, but I want to make the first row bold, set filtering for the first row, and to set the column widths to fit the content.

I know I can't do that in a CSV file, but I'm fine saving it as a file format that would.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Certainly. Write VBA code to format the cells after the CSV has been loaded into Excel, and then save it as an Excel .xlsx file. You can record a macro while manually applying the formatting, and then look at the generated source for the macro to see how it's done. (I'd do several smaller macros, so you have more manageable code blocks.)  You can put the macro code into a template for reuse. Once you start writing some code and have specific questions related to it, we can help.

Comment: That depends what is generating your CSV file, and whether it has the ablity to generate a xlsx file instead, or whether it has the ability to call something else (excel) that can format it for you. Give us a clue what is generating this CSV.